# Missing data points in seaborn boxplot

Tags: matplotlib, seaborn, boxplot, missing-data

How do I display a specific set of data in boxplots?

I have a dict like this.

```
data={'Unnamed: 0': [np.nan, np.nan, 'f', 's', np.nan, 's', np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
      'Unnamed: 1': ['e1','e1','e2','e2','e2','e3','e3','e3','e4','e4','e4'],
      'pH': [4, 6, 4, 6, 7, 5, 7, 8, 4, 6, 8],
      'sa': [43.0, 41.0, 34.0, 45.0, 12.0, 65.0, 34.0, 22.0, 2.2, 0.0, 0.0],
      'sb': [2.0, 1.5, 5.0, 5.2, 34.0, 76.0, 53.0, 4.3, 0.0, np.nan, 5.0],
      'sc': [4.2, 2.0, 66.0, 45.0, 15.0, 7.6, 9.0, np.nan, 6.0, 88.0, np.nan],
      'sd': [87.0, 47.0, 78.0, 90.0, 4.7, np.nan, 67.0, 3.4, 5.6, 0.0, np.nan],
      'se': [9.0, 3.3, 32.0, 4.5, 9.2, np.nan, 9.0, 34.0, 56.0, 2.1, np.nan],
      'sf': [7.0, 4.0, 3.0, 55.0, 67.0, 45.0, np.nan, np.nan, 65.0, 0.0, np.nan]}
```

I wrote the following code to show some data points.

```
# Read the dict.
df=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
df_1=df.set_index(["Unnamed: 1"])

# Remove irrelevant columns.
data_relevant=df_1[["pH","sa","sb","sc","sd","se"]]

# Get the enzyme activity of enzyme-of-interest.
a=data_relevant.loc["e4"]

# Boxplot.
fig,axes=plt.subplots(1,5,figsize=(24,8))
substrates=["sa","sb","sc","sd","se"]
fig.subplots_adjust(wspace=0.5)

for i, substrate in enumerate (substrates):
    axes[i].set_xlabel("pH",fontsize=24)
    axes[i].set_ylabel(substrate,fontsize=24)
    axes[i].tick_params(axis="x", labelsize=16)
    axes[i].tick_params(axis="y", labelsize=16)

    a.plot(x="pH",y=substrate,ax=axes[i%5],
           color="red",linestyle="None",marker="o",
           legend=None)
```

I tried to highlight these data points in boxplots.

```
for i, substrate in enumerate (substrates):
    axes[i].set_xlabel("pH",fontsize=24)
    axes[i].set_ylabel(substrate,fontsize=24)
    axes[i].tick_params(axis="x", labelsize=16)
    axes[i].tick_params(axis="y", labelsize=16)

    sns.boxplot(x="pH",y=substrate,data=data_relevant,
                width=0.5,
                ax=axes[i%5])

    a.plot(x="pH",y=substrate,ax=axes[i%5],
           color="red",linestyle="None",marker="o",
           legend=None)
```

Many data points were missing in the boxplots. Could someone show me why my code did not work? Thanks!

Comment: How about replacing the missing value with 0?
`df_1.fillna(0,inplace=True)`, it looks like it is displayed correctly on sns.

Comment: Thanks @r-beginners. I don't think nan caused the issue. I used sns.boxplot to make boxplots that include all data points of each category (here the category is substrate), but when I tried to display data points in a in those boxplots by using a.plot, some data points that could be seen by only running a.plot (without running sns.boxplot) were missing, and those data points did show up were displayed in wrong places. I'm not sure if it was caused by wrong codes in my Boxplot section.

Comment: It was my understanding that the intention of the question was that the SNS box plots would not be displayed as intended due to the effect of missing values.
If a normal plot is also a box plot, isn't `kind='box'` necessary?

Comment: I don't understand your question. You are not plotting the same dataset and using two different functions. On the one hand you're using boxplots to plot `data_relevant` and on the other hand you are using a line plot to plot the content of `a`. Please provide more information about what is the expected output if you want to get helpful answers